# Apply text decoration programmatically

Tags: codenameone

There's a text decoration in the theme(inside font) where we can choose underline and other features. Can we apply text decoration in a label programmatically?

Comment: Please show your code, very simply you can use inline styling on the label element to apply text decoration to the contents like `<label style="text-decoration: line-through;">My Text</label>`.

Answer (score 1):

This should produce an underline:

```
Style s = myComponent.getAllStyles();
s.setTextDecoration(Style.TEXT_DECORATION_UNDERLINE);
```